# Unable to identify Web object in UFT for webpage?

Tags: automation, hp-uft, browser-automation

```vbs
SystemUtil.Run "iexplore.exe", "https://www.jetairways.com/EN/IN/Home.aspx"  
wait (7)  
Set traverse=Browser("Jet Airways: Airlines").Page("Jet Airways: Airlines")  

traverse.WebEdit("placeholder:=From").Click  

traverse.Link("acc_name:=      This link will open Popup window for airport     selection.  ").WebElement("innerhtml:=All Airports","innertext:=All     Airports","outerhtml:=<strong>All Airports </strong>").Click  

traverse.WebTabStrip("html id:=ToC").Link("innerhtml:=Africa","innertext:=Africa").Click  
Set oDesc = Description.Create   
oDesc( "micclass" ).value = "Link"   
oDesc( "href" ).value = "https://www.jetairways.com/EN/IN/Home.aspx#"    
Set rc=Browser("creationtime:=0").Page("micClass:=page").ChildObjects(oDesc)  
msgbox rc.count
```

UFT is not bale to identify the link, lets say, **Johanesber** or **Port Elizabeth**,etc
    This is actually not working. Have tried many ways .
    Can some one help me fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The following code works for me, I cleaned up some of the spaces (and simplified the description a bit). I don't understand what you were trying to accomplish with the last lines of your script (counting the links).

I think the problem you were facing was probably to do with the fact that when you use descriptive programming (either inline with `:=` or using a `Description` object), the values are used as regular expressions and not as plain strings. This means you have to [escape regular expression characters](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) (in this case `(` and `)`) or else the values won't match.

```vbs
Set traverse=Browser("Jet Airways: Airlines").Page("Jet Airways: Airlines")  

traverse.WebEdit("placeholder:=From").Click

traverse.Link("acc_name:=This link will open Popup window for airport selection.").WebElement("html tag:=strong").Click

traverse.WebTabStrip("html id:=ToC").Link("innerhtml:=Africa","innertext:=Africa").Click 

traverse.Link("innertext:=Port Elizabeth \(PLZ\)").Click ' Note \( and \)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly fine. Tx a lot

Comment: Hi @abnv if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to write the link object and the pop up window object in two different lines
`traverse.Link("acc_name:=      This link will open Popup window for airport selection.  ")`

```
traverse.WebElement("innerhtml:=All Airports","innertext:=All Airports","outerhtml:=<strong>All Airports </strong>").Click
```

also try to use Regex if the property values contains spaces or symbols.